# I cannot start my elasticsearch after I put elasticsearch-analysis-ik in plugins

Tags: java, elasticsearch

elasticsearch version: 6.5.4

elasticsearch analysis ik version: 6.5.4

[2019-01-28T22:29:33,372][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [master] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load plugin descriptor for plugin directory [ik]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load plugin descriptor for plugin directory [ik]

Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/zhuzheng/Pakages/elasticsearch-6.5.4/plugins/ik/plugin-descriptor.properties

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `plugin-descriptor.properties` file to  `/Users/zhuzheng/Pakages/elasticsearch-6.5.4/plugins/ik/` folder, and start again.